# Why does this generic typescript function not recognise that the two parameters are of compatible types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

See this typescript code:

```js
type WrappedMouseEvent = {
  originalEvent: MouseEvent;
};

type WrappedWheelEvent = {
  originalEvent: WheelEvent;
};

type EventNameToWrappedEventMap = {
  mousemove: WrappedMouseEvent;
  wheel: WrappedWheelEvent;
};

type WrappedEventName = keyof EventNameToWrappedEventMap;

type WrappedEvent<EventName extends WrappedEventName> =
  EventNameToWrappedEventMap[EventName];

function wrappedCallback<EventName extends WrappedEventName>(
  originalEvent: WrappedEvent<EventName>["originalEvent"],
  callback: (event: WrappedEvent<EventName>) => void
) {
  callback({ originalEvent });
}
```

Where `callback` is called, there is an error:

```
Argument of type '{ originalEvent: MouseEvent | WheelEvent; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WrappedEvent<EventName>'.
  Type '{ originalEvent: MouseEvent | WheelEvent; }' is not assignable to type 'WrappedMouseEvent & WrappedWheelEvent'.
    Type '{ originalEvent: MouseEvent | WheelEvent; }' is not assignable to type 'WrappedWheelEvent'.
      Types of property 'originalEvent' are incompatible.
        Type 'MouseEvent | WheelEvent' is not assignable to type 'WheelEvent'.
          Type 'MouseEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'WheelEvent': deltaMode, deltaX, deltaY, deltaZ, and 3 more.(2345)
```

I would like to understand why this error occurs. I thought the use of the `EventName` type parameter for both `originalEvent` and `callback` would ensure that they were both dealing with the same WrappedEvent - either `MouseEvent` or `WheelEvent`. But from the error, it seems that `originalEvent` is simply being taken as `MouseEvent | WheelEvent`.

Comment: There's an error because the compiler can't perform the higher order reasoning that says "no matter what `K` is, `EventNameToWrappedEventMap[K]` is identical to `{originalEvent: EventNameToWrappedEventMap[K]["originalEvent"]}`.  That might be obvious to you, but it's beyond the compiler's abilities. It's similar to the issue described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I think that does address the question, thank you. I will read through that github issue, but it's not yet totally clear to me which aspect of what I'm doing is not supported i.e. where it differs from a normal generic function.

Comment: It would also be nice to know whether it's possible to fix (without using an assertion) using the approach described in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109

Comment: The question post does not ask how to fix it, it asks why the error occurs.  If your primary question is how to fix it, could you [edit] the question to make that clear?  If that does turn out to be your question then the ms/TS#47109 refactoring is probably just [as shown in `wrappedCallback` here](https://tsplay.dev/wj8bvm), but there doesn't seem to be a reason to make the code generic in the *key* at all; just make it generic in the event type (as shown in `wrappedCallback2` in the previous link) and it will work. Let me know how to proceed here.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `{ originalEvent }` as an argument to `callback`, TypeScript is inferring the type of `{ originalEvent }` to be `{ originalEvent: MouseEvent | WheelEvent; }`. This is because originalEvent is of type `WrappedEvent<EventName>["originalEvent"]`, which can be either a MouseEvent or a WheelEvent.

However, the callback function expects an argument of type WrappedEvent, which is either WrappedMouseEvent or WrappedWheelEvent. Since both of these types have different shapes, TypeScript is not able to infer the correct type and gives an error.

```
type WrappedMouseEvent = {
  originalEvent: MouseEvent;
};

type WrappedWheelEvent = {
  originalEvent: WheelEvent;
};

type EventNameToWrappedEventMap = {
  mousemove: WrappedMouseEvent;
  wheel: WrappedWheelEvent;
};

type WrappedEventName = keyof EventNameToWrappedEventMap;

type WrappedEvent<EventName extends WrappedEventName> =
  EventNameToWrappedEventMap[EventName];

function wrappedCallback<EventName extends WrappedEventName>(
  originalEvent: WrappedEvent<EventName>["originalEvent"],
  callback: (event: WrappedEvent<EventName>) => void
) {
  callback({ originalEvent } as WrappedEvent<EventName>);
}
```

Comment: But why is originalEvent inferred as MouseEvent | WheelEvent within wrappedCallback? Shouldn't it still be in terms of the EventName type parameter? It seems wrong for it to just be inferred as MouseEvent | WheelEvent. It's as if wrappedCallback wasn't generic at all.